# How to coat stainless steel?

Tags: electrochemistry, metal, conductivity, carbon-family

I am trying to coat stainless steel with carbon black. I am using Polyvinylidene fluoride PVDF 2% as a binder. I dip and I heat at 100C.

The coating that comes out is very fragile where you can blow on it and it would break.

What am I doing wrong? or is there a better method?

(Note: I am trying to maintain electrical conductivity between the steel and the carbon)

Comment: You might consult the authors of https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1359836819343483. Also, are you dipping into PVDF powder, or a solution?

Comment: solution with DMSO as a solvent.